# C# .Net How to determine if nullable DataMember value has been supplied

Tags: c#, soap, datacontract, option-type, datamember

I'm in the process of implementing a WCF/Soap service operation and have defined several of the data contract's members as not required (`IsRequired = false`).

My question relates to the following two scenarios...

- The client supplies a null value for the contract element (i:nil="true")
- The client does not supply the optional element (i.e. they send me a partial contract)

This problem is significant for both complex and nullable primitive types.  From what I can determine, the .Net serializer returns `null` in both scenarios, so my question is, can anyone recommend a way to determine whether an optional parameter was supplied in the SOAP request?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to add boolean *MemberSupplied* type members in your data contract. E.g.:

```
[DataContract]
public class EmployeeSearchParams
{
    [DataMember]
    public Employee Manager {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public bool ManagerSupplied {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, I've actually seen this suggested on another thread relating to a different issue.  I could use this approach if necessary, but I'd rather avoid it if possible as it's somewhat clunky.  I'm reluctant to change my contract to overcome the issue if I can avoid it.  Talking to a colleague yesterday, Java has a cleaner solution to the problem whereby the serializer provides the de-serialized object along with a wrapper for the raw request which provides properties to determine whether an optional element was supplied.

Comment: @Jonna that was my initial feeling about this approach as well, but although I call this a _workaround_, I came to accept this as the _cleaner_ solution. In my opinion it gets much more complicated to deal with the raw SOAP on the server side. Also consider the client side. If it's a straight forward WCF client, the client will have no way to choose whether to send null or omit the member on a _call-by-call_ basis.